# Making a command line program on linux (Raspbian or Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, python, raspbian

My objective is to make a program that can be installed and then operated using Terminal.

For example,

1. Pip is installed
2. We write `pip install numpy` in the terminal, and numpy is installed.

Challenges I'm facing:

1. We write `pip` in terminal or command line and it understands what pip is. I can't think of a way to get this done.
2. Once the above objective is completed, I need to pass multiple arguments like instead of `install numpy` it will look like `set color 4`.

The language I'm working on is Python and the OS is Raspbian.

Unfortunately, I have no idea if there exists a terminology for such problems, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of your main python program (say, `your_program`), and make it executable with `chmod a+x your_program`. Then typing `your_program` (or `./your_program`, if you don't have `.` in your `PATH`) will execute your program.

Details e.g. [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt), or in many other places.

You may want to modify your shell profile(s) to include some directory or directories in your `PATH` where you can put such programs (mine are `/usr/local/bin` for systemwide ones, and `$HOME/bin` for my personal scripts).

2) To access command line arguments, you can use `sys.argv`. An introduction is e.g. [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv), the library reference is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

You can use other libraries like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html) or [getopt](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/getopt.html) which in turn use `sys.argv` to help with parsing of command line options.

Comment: "You may want to modify your shell profile(s)..." I don't understand this part. I wrote `PATH=$PATH:/home/Desktop/sam` because my file is in `sam` folder which is on Desktop. I still have to write `./program_name` because `program_name` is not working. Can you please help?

Comment: If `/home/Desktop/sam` is in the `PATH`, and `program_name` is in `/home/Desktop/sam`, it *should* work. Check complete path (`echo $PATH`) for syntax errors. To be safe, check permissions of `sam` folder. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: Yes `/home/Desktop/sam` is now in the path but still I can't get rid of `./` my program name is `first.py` so should I add that to the path too?

Comment: a small update. It did worked. Thanks. However whenever I reboot my raspberry pi the path changes back to default. looking for solution but thanks.

Comment: The solution is to put it the `.profile` file (which most shells will use) in your home directory as something like `export PATH=$PATH:/home/Desktop/sam` (which most, but not all shells will understand). As I wrote, a more general scheme (and possibly symlinks) is what I prefer.

Comment: I did `sudo su`, `cd /etc` then `sudo vim profile`. Then I added the destination address in two PATH and exited by using `:wq`. Rebooted the computer and it worked. (Just an update for future readers) Final Heartiest thanks to @dirkt for helping me throughout the problem!